# how to quickly create <div> classes in vscode (javascript)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I know working in format .html 
Example: `.footer` key keyboard **tab** otomatics `<div class="footer">`

Why not working in format .js?

Comment: What you're describing about HTML is VS Code's native support for [Emmet](https://emmet.io/). For other languages than HTML, you might want to [set up or/and install custom snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

Comment: you can enable emmet also in other languages, it is already enabled in CSS, see the Emmet doc pages of the required setting

Answer (score 0):

It completes by Emmet.  After you install the Emmet. You can go to the setting. Under the Emmet: Include languages: add the language.
[image]

or go to the settings.json and add the code below:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact" }
```